# How to parse this data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large datafile dumped by Hadoop, over 300G. I have no choice but do a sampling.

```
fileName <-file(".\file.dat")
data <- sqldf("select * from fileName order by random(*) limit 1000")
```

After I have done this, I found data is a data frame object with 1000 obs, 1 variable.

There is no column name or anything associated with this, how to separate the data object into columns? right now it seems the columns were separated by tab.

Sample input row is

```
GxWdY-ixdsiqhy5P9Z-5Ug==    20140405    1896    329 3   0   1   NULL    2   6   2   140x140 476435  1   23  3199.0  3199.0  0.0 403 403
```

I suspect it should be `lapply(data, split(sep = "\t"))` or something?

Comment: ".\file.dat" should be "./file.dat" or ".\\file.dat".  Also the default sep is "," but your input data is not separated by commmas.  Try something like `read.csv.sql("./file.dat", sql = "...whatever...", sep = " ")`  or maybe `sep = "\t"` .  Read `?read.csv.sql`.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
data <- data.frame(rep("GxWdY-ixdsiqhy5P9Z-5Ug==    20140405    1896    329 3   0   1   NULL    2   6   2   140x140 476435  1   23  3199.0  3199.0  0.0 403 403",2))
```

Convert from a one-column data frame to a character vector:

```
datstr <- as.character(data[[1]])
```

Read as separate columns:

```
read.table(textConnection(datstr),sep="\t")
```

When I copy-pasted your example the tabs got lost, but if you really have them in your output that should work.  If you don't have spaces *within* any of your character columns, then you shouldn't even need the `sep` argument -- `read.table` uses generic whitespace separation by default.

Comment: thanks. But it gives error message "Error in textConnection(data) : invalid 'text' argument". I checked class(data[1]), it is still a data.frame

Comment: my sample row is just my first row of my data frame, how should I make your command work for whole data frame? It gives me the error I provided above. Thanks

Comment: please provide the results of `str(data)`.  If you what you have is a data frame with a single column, then `read.table(textConnection(as.character(data[[1]])))` should work.

Comment: oops, you did say that in your question.  Sorry.